# Best way to edit a nested protobuf field in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

For our admin page, we are using the basic

```
<SimpleForm>
  <TextInput>
  ...
</SimpleForm>
```

pattern.

One of our fields, however, is a nested protobuf object. Although it's nested, most of the fields of this protobuf object are fairly basic. I tried using dot notation like

```
<TextInput
  label="nestedField"
  source="ProtobufObject.nestedField"
/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a more straightforward way of handling this other than creating a custom input?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ProtobufObject other than what I just read on the google site. I have an api that returns JSON below. To show the event name, source="event.eventName". If your payload isn't JSON, you'll need to convert it in your data provider.

```
[
  {
    "competitionName": "XYZ",
    "competitionStatus": "SCHEDULED",
    "id": 107,
    "createdAt": "2018-08-30T03:53:37.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-30T03:53:37.000Z",
    "event": {
      "eventName": "XYZ",
      "eventDesc": "Something",
      "startDate": "2018-09-13T07:00:00.000Z",
      "startTime": "2018-08-30T01:00:58.482Z",
      "endTime": "2018-08-30T03:00:58.484Z",
      "eventLocation": "Gym",
      "competitionId": 107,
      "createdAt": "2018-08-30T03:53:37.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-08-30T03:53:37.000Z",
    }
  }
]
```